# SQL great than inside Count function

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I am wanting to do this, but it is throwing an sql error:

```
SELECT COUNT(items > 0) as totalItems FROM testTable

Incorrect syntax near '>'.
```

My intent is to count all items that are greater than 0 here.  It works great in MySQL, but SQL Server 2008 doesn't like it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Server, you need a `case` statement:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN items > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as totalItems
FROM testTable;
```

You can use `COUNT()` if you do:

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN items > 0 THEN 1 END) as totalItems
FROM testTable;
```

But I prefer using `SUM()`.

Or, if `items` is non-negative:

```
SELECT COUNT(NULLIF(items, 0)) as totalItems
FROM testTable;
```

Comment: I've never loved MySQL more than right now =).  Why the preference?

Comment: @Shackrock . . . The treatment of booleans as integers is one of the features of MySQL that I actually like.

Comment: @Shackrock . . . I do not like that `count(2)` = `count(1)`.  It seems easily prone to misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well, that query by itself could just be

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as totalItems 
FROM testTable
WHERE items > 0
```

But if it's part of a larger query that the `WHERE` clause doesn't apply to then you can use

```
SUM(CASE WHEN items > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

As Gordon suggests.